# Is the PHP Composer Repository Protocol Defined?

Tags: php, composer-php, packages.json

In composer, PHP's package management system, its possible to [configure a repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md).  A repository is a system that composer will "ask" when it needs to find a package.  i.e.

**Composer**: Hey, repository, where can I find the `foo/bar` package

**Repository**: You can find `foo/bar` (in this VCS repository|in this `dist` zip file)

By default, composer will look at the [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) repository when it wants to find something.

Are the technical details (i.e. a protocal) of the above plain english description defined anywhere?  Or, put a different way, is there a description of the `packages.json` schema file anywhere?

[The documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#composer) is a little scant on this, saying only

> The main repository type is the composer repository. It uses a single packages.json file that contains all of the package metadata.

And even this is (in certain contexts) inaccurate, as a `packages.json` file can include other `json` files to avoid a super large `packages.json`.

Is this a well defined protocol, or is this a case of the composer source being the only source of truth on how a "composer repository" should behave?

Comment: I wonder, what is your goal?

Comment: @TomášVotruba My goal is to study how a composer repository works so I can better understand it :)

Comment: I understand that. But what do you plan to achieve?

Comment: For sources, just search 'composer private svn/git repo'

Comment: @TomášVotruba I plan to achieve a better understanding of how composer repositories work and what its possible to do with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a lookt [satis](https://github.com/composer/satis). It is a open-source Package Repository Generator for Composer. It generates a Composer Repository file. That file will hopefully tell you more about the `packages.json` schema. It is indeed a bit weird that Composer doesn't have a good description about this on their website.